# Getting basic Elite Dangerous Galnet News for application

Tags: elite-dangerous

I might have to ask this question on stack overflow... but since I am not really asking for code, and I am just asking for a good source of basic Galnet News from the game Elite Dangerous, I figured I'd ask it here.

I might make a multipurpose 3rd party application for the community of Elite Dangerous. One of the things I'd like the application to do is show Galnet News, with maybe a twist (I'm thinking about notifying the user about news regarding their faction for example).

But I don't know where I can get a simple text version of galnet news, does anybody know of such a website, or wherever I can get it? All idea's are welcome, code is not needed (but I am using c# .net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed: https://www.elitedangerous.com/en/galnet-rss

You can parse this with any RSS reader.

Answer (score 0):

The only out of game resource I've seen for news is the powerplay report page:

http://www.powerplayreport.com/